# Visual studio code UI is acting weird

Tags: visual-studio-code

my visual studio code gets like this when its not running as the main windows, its kinda hard when I want to use split screen

[image: why does it looks like this?]
[image: condition when split screen]

Comment: disable graphics accelleration

Comment: Have you tried closing/reopening, force closing with task manager, restarting your computer, and checking for graphics card updates?

Comment: @Samathingamajig, its always like this even when i do that

Comment: @rioV8 where to find it?

Comment: command line option

Comment: @rioV8 tried, didn't work

Comment: which command line option did you use

Comment: @rioV8 disable hardware acceleration

Comment: what was the command you tried to start VSC